# Adding Formatted Numbers To A MySQL Select Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, numbers

I'm building a simple music website which has a set of albums on the selection page. On the left will be a group of album covers, and on the right will be the related album title and band name. Each album will be given a number, which will be referenced in the title/band name. Kind of like on a magazine contents page.

So my `SELECT` statement looks like:

```
$albums_sql = "SELECT albums.*, bands.name FROM albums LEFT JOIN bands ON albums.band = bands.id LIMIT $offset, $album_limit";
$albums_res = mysqli_query($con, $albums_sql);

while($album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($albums_res)){

    $album_id = $album["id"];
    $album_added = $album["added"];
    $album_band = $album["name"];
    $album_title = $album["title"];
    ....
```

And my displayed title looks like:

```
<div class=\"listWords\">$album_number ... <strong>$album_band: $album_title</strong></div>
```

Now this displays:

> ... The Band Name: The Album Name

But I obviously want it to display:

> 01 ... The Band Name: The Album Name

How do I get it to display a 2 digit numeral value for each row that is selected from the table using `PHP`?

Here's where I imagine I should create a number:

```
$albums_sql = "SELECT albums.*, bands.name FROM albums LEFT JOIN bands ON albums.band = bands.id LIMIT $offset, $album_limit";
    $albums_res = mysqli_query($con, $albums_sql);

    while($album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($albums_res)){

        $album_id = $album["id"];
        $album_added = $album["added"];
        $album_band = $album["name"];
        $album_title = $album["title"];
        ....
        $album_number = ( Create a number based on how many are selected from the abover select statement )
```

Comment: can you show `$albums_res` output? Where is  `$album_number` comming from? Is it the ID you would like to display, or just a row number?

Comment: The `$album_number` is what I'm trying to create, based on the number of rows selected from the Select statement. So if each page selects 12 albums, they will be listed as album 1 - 12. I just don't know how to number each selected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be as simple as

```
$i=0;
while($album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($albums_res)){
    $album_number = $i++;
    $album_id = $album["id"];
    $album_added = $album["added"];
    $album_band = $album["name"];
    $album_title = $album["title"];
    ...
```

and then if you want 0 padded numbers

```
echo sprintf("%02d",$album_number);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I changed the `echo sprintf("%02d",$album_number);` to `$album_number = sprintf("%02d",$album_number);` to better impliment it into my code and all is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable as a counter outside of the while loop, and increment at each iteration.

```
$album_index = 0;
while($album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($albums_res)){
        $album_number = $album_index++;
        $album_id = $album["id"];
        $album_added = $album["added"];
        $album_band = $album["name"];
        $album_title = $album["title"];
```